# Pandas create new column based on 2 other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

I have DataFrame holds 2 columns.
The first one has lower case letter and the other one has True/False values.
I'm trying to create third column that changes a lower case letter into an upper case if it marked as True at the second column.

this line won't work for some reason.

```
df['result_seq'] = df['Letters'].apply(lambda x: x.upper() if df['bool_array'] is True else x)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Use `mask`: `df['Letters'].mask(df['bool_array'], df['Letters'].str.upper())`

Comment: It didn't work unfortunately

Comment: Well, too bad. I guess more details on *how* it did not work could have gotten me to propose an alternative.

Comment: It's just the I ran the comment as you showed and all of the letters stayed lower case even if they had True on bool_array at the same row :)

Comment: Have you assigned the output? `df['result_seq'] = ...`

Comment: Ohhh sorry i havn't i though those are inplace changes. 
It works, very cool. Thanks!